# Why does the print(f.close()) return None in the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

In the following code, I assumed that the file gets already closed, but then why does `print(f.close())` return `None` instead of an error?

```
f = None
for i in range(5):
    with open("mytextfile.txt", 'w') as f:
        if i>2:
            break

print(f.close())
```

If anyone can help or explain how it works, it would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the print part**, Because `close()` does not return any value.

**And for the error part**, I think you are just trying to close the file that is already close and although it causes error to do anything on closed file, there is exception `to close it again`, because it check for `f.closed` and since is is already closed (finds it to be `True`, it doesnt raise an error, which you can overide, but I dont think it would be good to do so.